# Hide JButton after click on it

Tags: java

I want to have 2 things:

1. Hide my "PLAY" button after I click on it.
2. To leave other buttons at the same positions in which they were before I hid the PLAY button

   ```
   public class MusicPlayer {
       public static void main (String[] args) {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main window");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
       frame.setResizable(false);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

       JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
       JButton b1 = new JButton("PLAY");
       JButton b2 = new JButton("PAUSE");
       JButton b3 = new JButton("STOP");
       GridBagConstraints layout = new GridBagConstraints();
       layout.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 5, 0);
       layout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
       layout.weighty = 1;

       panel.add(b1, layout);
       panel.add(b2, layout);
       panel.add(b3, layout);
       frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
       b1.setBackground(Color.green);
       b2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
       b3.setBackground(Color.red);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: doesn't `setVisible(false);` work?

Comment: I tried to put it in function like this:
b1.addActionListener (new Graj());

 static class Graj implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
  }
  
  public void hideButton (ActionEvent e, JButton b) {
   b.setVisible(false);
  }
 }

Comment: add actionlistner to post.

Comment: Something like this?
'button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
              button.setVisible(false);
            }
}'

Comment: @wuwunio64 yes.doesn't it work?

Comment: @FastSnail yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add action listener to your **PLAY** button `b1`.

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     b1.setVisible(false); 
  } 
}
```

It shall do the job of hiding for you.

Comment: Glad that you did it :)